# Data not stored in the MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, postman

I'm connecting node backend to MySQL database. When I try to add data, I'm getting a success message, but it's not getting added. Interesting part is that, initially it worked (just once), but now it's not storing the information in the database.

```
    const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');



const app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.json());

const mysqlconnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'customerdb',
    multipleStatements: true
})

mysqlconnection.connect((err) => {
    if (!err) console.log('DB Successfully Connected !')

    else
        console.log('Database Not Connected \n Error' + JSON.stringify(err));
})

app.listen(3000, (req, res) => {
    console.log("Server Running on Port 3000");
})

// Insert a customer

app.post('/customers', (req, res) => {

    let data = req.body;
    var sql = "SET @id = ?;SET @firstname = ?;SET @lastname = ?;SET @password = ?; \
    CALL CustomerAddOrUpdate(@_id,@_firstname,@_lastname,@_password);";

    mysqlconnection.query(sql, [data.id, data.firstname, data.lastname, data.password], (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (!err)
            res.send(rows)
        else
            res.send(err);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds interesting.
If it worked once and the API always succeed, maybe `CustomerAddOrUpdate` mysql function was not written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...)";
```

Can't tell you what is the problem with your code, because it looks fine to me.

Comment: I'm using stored procedures, so I don't think your code will work.